# Ruby/NetSSH try username and password only once?

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

Is there a way to fail immediately after trying a username and password sequence with `Net::SSH.start()`? I am looking to test to see if credentials work then stop afterwards, here is the code that I have

```
output = 0
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "pass") do |ssh|
   output = ssh.exec! 'echo "1"'
end
puts output
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should restrict authentication to `password` only, and no prompts or retries:

```
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user',  
               :password     => 'pass', 
               :auth_methods => [ 'password' ],
               :number_of_password_prompts => 0)
```

**`:auth_methods`** restricts SSH to only try those authentication methods which are listed in the array. In this case we only want to try password authentication.

**`:number_of_password_prompts`** only works with the `password` auth method, and if you set it to zero it will never prompt for a password, even if the authentication fails.

Comment: I couldn't find this anywhere in the docs, and it occurs to me now that this is a `ssh-config` option, thank you for this!